# Restore WhatsApp data to respective chat locations

Tags: restore, whatsapp-messenger

My phone has been running low on space lately. WhatsApp gave me the low storage error and then crashed. After freeing a couple of gigabyte on my phone, I went back to WhatsApp, only to discover that my chat history (for all contacts) has been wiped out. However, I discovered that in my phone's settings, it says WhatsApp is using 70 GB (probably all my WhatsApp chat data).

I don't think any files are corrupted, because I went to the WhatsApp data folder in the "My Files" app and I was able to play WhatsApp videos from there.

How can I get my chat history to show up again in their respective WhatsApp chats?